# Apply outer style to Gatsby StaticImage using twin.macro

Tags: css, reactjs, gatsby

I am using StaticImage from gatsby-plugin-image together with twin.macro for CSS styling and followed this guide: https://github.com/ben-rogerson/twin.examples/tree/master/gatsby-styled-components#getting-started

```
...
import tw, { css, styled, theme } from 'twin.macro'
import { StaticImage } from 'gatsby-plugin-image'
...

    <StaticImage
      imgStyle={tw`rounded-lg shadow-2xl`}
      style={tw`p-4`}
      src="../images/image.jpeg"
      width={300}
      quality={95}
      formats={['AUTO', 'WEBP', 'AVIF']}
      alt="Description"
    />
```

Styling the inner img element with 'imgStyle' works with twin.macro. However applying the same technique for the style property of StaticImage leads to the following error:

**Styles shouldn’t be added within a `style={...}` prop**

How can I apply twin.macro to the style property of StaticImage?

Comment: Are you sure there is `style` prop for `StaticImage`?...

Comment: yes, at least it is mentioned in the documentation: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-plugin-image/#staticimage 

style:
CSSProperties
Description: Inline styles applied to the outer wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to the Gatsby Image plugin docs:](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-plugin-image/)

> The images are loaded and processed at build time, so there are
> restrictions on how you pass props to the component. The values need
> to be statically-analyzed at build time, which means you can’t pass
> them as props from outside the component, or use the results of
> function calls, for example. You can either use static values, or
> variables within the component’s local scope.

So the code should look like this:

```
// Also OK
// A variable in the same file is fine.
const width = 300;
const height = 300;
const imgStyle= tw`rounded-lg shadow-2xl`;
export function Dino() {
  // This works because the value can be statically-analyzed
  const height = (width * 16) / 9
  return <StaticImage 
      src="../images/image.jpeg" 
      width={width} 
      height={height} 
      style={imgStyle}
  />
}
```

Comment: This does not explain, why it is working fine with the imgStyle attribute. It is only not working for the the outer style property.

Comment: @NetUserHH maybe it works as there is no need to be statically-analyzed at build time and styles will be applied when view will be rendered

Comment: @NetUserHH Could you try my updated answer?

Comment: that helped! However, please change your answer to the style property instead of imgStyle of StaticImage.